# Pass string as regex pattern input. (non-scalar error)

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11

I am trying to perform a regex search, but instead of typing the pattern (e.g std::regex reg = "\.") I want to **give regex a string input**. Here is my code where I convert string to const char* and pass it to regex_search:

```
void trigger_regex(string name, string body)
    {

      map<string,string>::iterator it;
      it=test.mydata.find(name);
      if( it == test.mydata.end())
      {
        std::cout<<"REGEX not found"<<endl;
      }
      else
        cout << "Found REGEX with name: " << it->first << " and rule: " << it->second << endl ;

        string subject = body;
        string rule = it -> second;
        const char * pattern = rule.c_str();
        regex reg = (pattern);
        smatch match;    

        while (regex_search (subject,match,reg)) {
          for (auto x:match) std::cout << x << " ";
          std::cout << std::endl;
          body = match.suffix().str();
        }
     }
```

I get error:

> conversion from 'const char*' to non-scalar type 'std::regex {aka
>   std::basic_regex}' requested
>        regex reg1 = (rule1);

any help pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at e.g. [this `std::regex` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex) you will see that the constructor taking just a string (the second constructor in the list) is marked `explicit`. That means you must *explicitly* use that constructor, you can't just hope to convert a string to a `std::regex` object.

In other words, the solution is to define and initialize the object like this

```
std::regex reg1{pattern};
```